# How to page through top-stories on Reddit?

Tags: web-services, api, reddit

Maybe I'm just tired, but I can't figure out how to use the Reddit-API to retrieve stories properly despite staring at the API docs [1] for an hour..

For example if I GET the URL `http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/top.json?limit=5` then I get 5 story elements.

At the bottom it says `before : null` and `after : "t3_12vgdt"`, which corresponds to the `name` property of the last returned story-item.

How to interpret this? And how do I paginate to the next 5 items, items 6 - 10?

[1] referenced here: https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the query parameter `after=t3_12vgdt`. Because there is already an existing query parameter, `limit=5`, you have to use `&` to add the additional parameter.

`http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/top.json?limit=5&after=t3_12vgdt`

You'll notice if you use the actual reddit pages (remove the `.json`) that this is exactly how it behaves when you click on the next link.

Comment: "Why was I confused?"
Based on your question, I would say because you were tired. Happens to the best of us.